# Вызов функции при загрузке

Tags: javascript, jquery

Есть некая функция, точнее часть об общего скрипта, вызываемая при нажатии:

```
$('.list a').click(function(e) {
e.preventDefault();
$(select.find('option')[$(this).attr('data-select-index')]).attr('selected', 'selected');
select.trigger('change');
});
```

Весь скрипт берет select и превращает его в список со ссылками, при нажатии на которые происходит выбор опций select-a используя `data-select-index`. Как после обработки всего скрипта принудительно выполнить данную часть для первого пункта списка? То есть, чтоб после создания списка был выбран первый пункт. Пробовал вызывать функцию для конкретного пункта через .onload, но, результат нулевой.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Для удобства перенесем выбор пункта `select` в отдельную функцию, которой будем передавать данные по кликнутой ссылке. Соответственно, после обработки `select`а просто вызываем эту функцию с нужным (самым первым) `data-select-index`.

```js
$('.list a').click(function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  var index = $(this).attr('data-select-index');
  selectItem(index);
});

function selectItem(index) {
  $(select.find('option')[index]).attr('selected', 'selected');
  select.trigger('change');
}
var veryFirstLink = $('.list a').eq(0);
selectItem(veryFirstLink.attr('data-select-index'));
```

Comment: Спасибо большое. То, что нужно!